# All partial views items are the same when using Nested Content in Partial view I'm using Umbraco 8

Tags: c#, caching, partial-views, umbraco8

I'm trying to make a webticker as a partial view which will take its settings and items from a document type under the parent page but all partial views has the same nested content items as the first request (all other properties are working fine).

```
@{
    var mainWebticker = Umbraco.Content(Guid.Parse("bae542f8-5769-4eb3-aa39-d5e0b6b675e9"));
}

@Html.Partial("Webticker", mainWebticker)

@{
     var webticker2 = Umbraco.Content(Guid.Parse("a6fa8c8e-fd5c-4b4f-b9e0-f324dcc053cc")); 
}

@Html.Partial("Webticker", webticker2 )
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the doc type again solved the problem. This is a solution but not the answer for why is that happening